# Xodus find entities api like inSet operation

Tags: xodus

Is there a possibility to query Xodus EntityStore by the property as "inset" operation? This is not possible based on existing Xodus API but maybe this is possible to do with custom Comparable and ComparableBinding by `PersistentEntityStore.registerCustomPropertyType()`?

Comment: What do you mean by "inset" operation?

Comment: @lehvolk I mean find entities by is property in a set (like SQL's IN operation). Xodus API gives a possibility to find by equality and find in range.

Answer (score 2):

There are a `union` and `intersect` operations in `EntityIterable` interface so you could use them:

```
txn.findWithProp("User", "name1").union(txn.findWithProp("User", "name2"))
```

PS: you can take a look to the [xodus-dnq](https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus-dnq) there are API for persistent model and API for retrieving data from database.